# How to store json data in static file in Django view, and call this function from another function ?

Tags: python, json, django

So , here below my view.py  ( not quite work )  I want to store d.json in data folder under statics subfloder using this code below. How to tell Djson to dump this d.json.

**Myapp>statics>data>d.json**

```
def getjson(request)
    import ujson as json
    import pandas
    import numpy as np

    df = pandas.DataFrame({
        "time" : [1,2,3,4,5],
        "temp" : np.random.rand(5)
    })

    d = [
        dict([
            (colname, row[i])
            for i,colname in enumerate(df.columns)
        ])
        for row in df.values
    ]
    jdata = json.dumps(d)
    return jdata
```

what am i missing here ? recommendation would be appreciate.

My goal is ultimately call this function within another function to do something else, can I call this from another function within the view ? something like

```
def anotherfunction(request):
  getjson()
  # do something else
  return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view** is just a Python function that takes an **HttpRequest** as its first parameter and returns an instance of **HttpResponse**

so `def getjson(request):` is just a `function`, **not** `view`, because doesn't return instance of **HttpResponse** and **yes** you can call it (function) from another function or view

You can dump your data to specified location, using smth like this:

```
import json, os
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from your_project_dir.settings import BASE_DIR

local_file_path = '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(resolve(request.path).app_name, 'statics', 'd.json')
global_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, local_file_path)

with open(global_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(data, outfile)
```